# Replacing max(columnname) with a different query

Tags: sql-server, max

I am working with a number of tables, where developer used 'max(columnname)' on its own to get the most recent entry in a column. This can cause performance bottlenecks so I'm trying to replace max(columnname) with the alternative queries.

I thought of:

`select [column name], max(1) from [table] order by [column name]`

and

```
select top 1 [column name] from [table] order by [column name] desc
```

Do you think one of the above would work well? If not, do you have any suggestions how to build a better query?

Comment: What do *you* think? Did you try? If one query works better than the other is pretty easy to find out by simply trying. That being said, your first query is not valid. Including your *actual* SQL will increase the chance of getting useful answers.

Comment: What about SCOPE or IDENTITY, since they are meant for finding out latest inserts http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: Why you're thinking that max(columnname) will cause performance loss? You just have to have index on this column, so is it reasonable to have column data type something small to conserve index space (integer or datetime - what kind of data you actually need). Unindexed nvarchar(max) is not good choice of course :)

Comment: what is the purpose of finding the max(column)? is it to find the next id or to show the latest record? please expand on why you need this information as this may lead to a better solution.